# Chef cookbook: undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, azure, chef-infra

I'm having a problem with a chef cookbook that create several shared filesystems.

This is the fragment that is giving me problems:

```
sii_share_share "ansible" do
    remote_path "//#{ node['sii_base']['utils_storage_account_name'] }.file.core.windows.net/ansible"
    local_path "/opt/ansible"
    fstype "cifs"
    dir_owner "root"
    dir_group "sysadmin"
    dir_mode "0770"
    file_mode "0660"
    cifs_credentials_file "/root/.smb.utils.credentials"
end
```

The error is "undefined local variable or method `local_path' for #<#:0x00000000047b3ed8>"

This error is happening with these versions:

> Chef-client: 14.1.12
>
> ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

With previous versions (chef-client 13.6 and ruby 2.3.1p112) this is working fine. I'm running these cookbooks in Azure, using the Linux Chef extension.

Have anyone experimented something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a custom resource you made yourself?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom resource!

Comment: Please show the code for it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your resource is using deprecated property naming.

- Verify that the `sii_share_share` resource has a property named `local_path`
- If it does then you need to verify that all of the code inside the
  resource itself refers to the `local_path` property using
  `new_resource.local_path` and not `local_path`. This has been a
  [pending deprecation that went in to effect with Chef Client 14](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_namespace_collisions.html).

You should always review [breaking changes](https://docs.chef.io/release_notes.html#breaking-changes) before making the move between major versions of Chef Client. The end of each chef-client run also outputs deprecation messages as a warning before these breaking changes go in to place.

Comment: Yeah! This worked for me. I had to add 'new_resource' to the properties and it worked. Thank you very much!